# Regex autoincrement replacements

Tags: regex, perl, pcre, auto-increment, textwrangler

is there a string in regular expressions that can instruct it to autoincrement it's replacements, whether they be numbers or letters.

Thank you

for instance, I have strings that should be number `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` but they are currently numbered as `1, 1, 1, 1, 1`

how would I replace the number in those 5 individual similar strings to be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

Comment: Could you provide an example of the autoincrementing you are looking for?  Also, regex syntax is not universal; what language will you use?

Comment: I use TextWrangler's grep/regex, example added

Comment: @RD, thank you.  According to TextWrangler's docs, they use Perl-Compatable regular expressions (pcre)

Comment: Ah, is there an autoincrement function with prce regex or should I ask the stack universe a new question

Comment: Is "1, 1, 1, 1, 1" the exact string, or is there more to match of besides a comma and space before incrementing?

Comment: there is more to each individual string, I'll be looking to implement your answer tomorrow and comment if there is difficulting adapting it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the syntax of TextWrangler; however, it uses `pcre` so this should be what you want as long as you have a way to assign an initial value to your incrementing variable (in this case, I use `$ii`)... the script below replaces any occurrence of "pizza-x" with "pizza-0", "pizza-1"...

```
@foo = ('pizza', 'pizza-a', 'pizza-b', 'pizza-c');
$ii = 0;
foreach (@foo) {
    $_ =~ s/(pizza-)[a-z]/"$1".$ii++/e;
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Results...

```
[mpenning@mpenning-t60 Desktop]$ perl foo.pl 
pizza
pizza-0
pizza-1
pizza-2
```

The magic comes from `s///e;` and `$ii++`; be sure you enclose the non-incrementing string in quotes and concatenate with a period.

Alternatively, just do your auto-increment mangling with `perl -pi -e '$ii = 0; s/something/"here".$ii++/e` ` directly on the text file (make a backup copy first, of course).